# Code Runner Icon not showing in Visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Today I opened my VS Code editor and I saw that the code runner icon had disappeared despite that it was installed. I could only see the default run code option. Please help me solve it, I also tried uninstalling and installing the extension again and also did the same with vscode but the problem still persists![the run option os of default vscode not coderunner][1]

Comment: I think you failed to insert the image correctly into your question. Can you try that again? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the extensions and then search for code runner after this install it and then it will appear.

Answer (score -1):

This button does not disappear, but is integrated with the original "`Run Python file in Terminal`" button in the Python file. Click this button and it will display two run options: "`Run Code`" provided by Code Runner extension and "`Run Python file in Terminal`" provided by Python extension.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check the pyhon ... program language version and select the correct one if you are using several different versions.